# MySQL sort after argument in IN()

Tags: php, mysql

I have string containing a lot of IDs corresponding to my database.
Like:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

I then do a mySQL query to select all those rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (".$myIDs.")
```

I want mySQL to return the rows in the order they are in my IN() select.

So if I instead had

```
2,1,3,4,5
```

I would have #2 as first row, when fetching in PHP.
Without any ORDER BY it looks like it return the lowest ID first.

Let me know if you need further exlpanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this via the [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (2,1,3,4,5) ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 2,1,3,4,5) DESC
```

That is:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
  `id` IN (".$myIDs.")
ORDER BY
  FIELD(`id`, ".$myIDs.") DESC
```

More in this blog post: [*Sorting MySQL rows using column values*](http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/sorting-mysql-rows-using-column-values/).

Comment: @jensgram I tried your query but I get output in descending or ascending order my query is `SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE question_level IN (1,2,1,2,3,2,4,2,3,2) ORDER BY FIELD(question_level,1,2,1,2,3,2,4,2,3,2);` 
But I am getting result in like 1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3

Comment: @NageshKatke I would expect `FIELD` to take unique values (I have a hard time comprehending how one would otherwise use it for ordering.) The distinct values you've provided are `1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: @jensgram what would be the solution for duplicate values

Comment: @NageshKatke Sounds like a separate question to me :)

Comment: @jensgram I already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194874/fetch-record-in-order-with-in-clause-having-duplicate-values-in-in-clause

Answer (score 0):

You might use `order by` with `case ... end`, though part between `case` and `end` should be generated by PHP:

```
select
    *    
from
    table
where
    id in (2, 1, 3, 4, 5)
order by
    case id
        when 2 then 1
        when 1 then 2
        when 3 then 3
        when 4 then 4
        when 5 then 5
    end asc
```

Answer (score 0):

you want the [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

```
$list = "1,2,....";
$sql = "select * from table where id in($list) order by find_in_set($id, '$list')";
```

another (probably faster) option is to do sorting in php:

```
$list = array(2, 3, ...);
$s    = implode(',', $list);
$sth  = mysql_query("select * from table where id in($s)");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($sth))
    $rows[$r->id] = $r;

$sorted_rows = array();
foreach($list as $id)
   $sorted_rows[] = $rows[$id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, though `FIELD` is probably the way to go in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (2,1,3,4,5) ORDER BY `id` = 2 DESC, `id` = 1 DESC,`id` = 3 DESC, `id` = 4 DESC, `id` = 5 DESC
```

Comment: But that would require I know the length of $myIDs - or I loop it in PHP and generate SQL?

Comment: Yes you'd have to loop through your array and build the SQL. `FIELD` is probably the way to go, just putting another option out there.