# Select with set order in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT title,id FROM table1 WHERE id IN ('2','7','4','10')
```

The result set is ordered by id by default, but I need it in the exact order of numbers in above set.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function should be able to do this:

```
SELECT
    title, id
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    id IN ('2', '7', '4', '10')
ORDER BY FIELD(id, '2', '7', '4', '10')
```

See also [*MySQL sort after argument in IN()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291959/mysql-sort-after-argument-in-in/6292023#6292023).